# Use of "gehen" and "laufen" with animals

Tags: meaning-in-context

I said this in a conversation:

> Die Katze ist in die Küche gegangen.

and was told this sounds odd in German, almost as if the cat were a human carrying an umbrella or something, according to one German-speaking friend.  One would apparently say:

> Die Katze ist in die Küche gelaufen.

even if the cat was walking at normal speed and not running.  Is there some rule in German that only humans use *gehen* and all other animals use *laufen* for ordinary walking?

Comment: For me "gehen" sounds completely normal for animals, too.

Comment: I've read of such a rule, the gist being that "gehen" absolutely implies the use of human feet, and therefore all animals are fundamentally incapable of "gehen". I've never seen it enforced, however, and never agreed with it. It's probably one of those decades-old traditions that keep being repeated long after they've lost all relevance.

Comment: Opposed to all answers here I am convinced that *gehen* can **not** be used in the context of animals (unlike they are "almost human and carrying an umbrella"). I linked a *Duden* and *Spiegel* article below one answer. My advice is to refrain from gehen in the context of animals, then you are on the safe side.

Comment: @RoyPJ: zum Zwiebelfisch sage ich nur: [*,Oha!' flüsterte der Junge; ,da **geht** ein Pferd — ein Schimmel — das muß der Teufel reiten — wie kommt ein Pferd nach Jevershallig?'*](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/der-schimmelreiter-3488/11)

Comment: @Takkat Allerdings ist das im Schimmelreiter direkte Rede eines Jungen, deswegen muss es noch lange nicht richtig sein. Aber ok, das zeigt, dass es mindestens umgangssprachlich verwendbar ist.

Comment: @RoyPJ: Ich muss Dich enttäuschen, wenn es seit Charles Darwin noch niemand getan hat: Der Mensch *ist* ein Tier. Denkbar wäre, dass nur das Laufen auf 2 Füßen als Gehen bezeichnet wird, aber dann würden Tauben gehen, Katzen nur sporadisch ein paar Schritte. Dagegen spricht, dass man extra 'der aufrechte Gang' sagt, also gibt es auch einen auf allen Vieren. Beim Essen/Fressen macht man auch die Unterscheidung Mensch vs. andere Tiere - jedoch nicht dogmatisch.

Comment: @userunknown Jetzt wirst du philosophisch. Im Duden wird in der Definition von Tier unter anderem genannt, dass es nicht logisch denken kann. Jedoch hat mich das dazu gebracht "Fuß" nachzuschlagen und entgegen meiner Vermutung schließt dieser durchaus auch Pfoten mit ein.

Comment: Tja, und, als logisch denkender Mensch, schließt Du Dich dem Duden an? Es steht Dir frei den Standpunkt des Duden in Frage zu stellen und zu dem Schluss zu kommen, dass es sich vielleicht um Fachidioten handelt, wenn sie bis heute nicht gemerkt haben, dass Tiere logisch denken können. Es gibt unzählige Beobachtungen im Tierreich, die das nahe legen. In zu vielen Fragen stümpert der Duden rum, als dass ich vor ihm noch Respekt hätte, selbst in Sprachfragen ohne ideologisches Gewicht ist er nicht verlässlich.

Comment: @user unknown: "Der Mensch ist ein Tier". Ja, und Männer sind Schweine? <g>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, this seems to be an issue of the (in)famous *gehen - laufen* "conflict" and has nothing to do with animals or humans.

This depends very much on the region. Here in Austria, you would only say *laufen* if you really mean *running*. So to my ears, your first sentence

> Die Katze ist in die Küche gegangen.

sounds like perfect german. It does not make a difference if the subject in question is a person or an animal.

In some parts of Germany on the other hand, people use *laufen* to express regular *walking* all the time. That sounds odd to me, but it is completely normal for a lot of people.

So

> Die Katze ist in die Küche gelaufen.

would mean to me that the cat was definitely running, but for a lot of people it would probably mean that the cat was just walking. It really depends on your conversation partner.

Both sentences are completely correct, of course, and everyone will understand what you mean in general. There is no rule that I know of that *gehen* kann only be used with humans, animals can do that too.

Comment: I was totally the same opinion, but according to the Duden, gehen implies the use of "Füße", while a cat only has "Pfoten"... https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen#Bedeutung1

Comment: We will never reach a conclusion on this one I guess....but at least in Austria, animals definitely are able to "gehen", and so are babies at a certain age, and I would also use "gehen" for a handstand...everything else would sound really odd to any Austrian. But I know this is a neverending discussion :-)

Comment: My conversation partner was from Hamburg, so sounds like this is a regional thing... but I'll use laufen with animals from now on.

Answer (score 4):

Nach dem [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GG04934#XGG04934) ist *gehen* ein etymologisch altes Wort mit indoeuropäischen Wurzeln:

> urverwandtschaft bietet litt. żèngti schreiten, gehen (Bopp gl. 133a), am bedeutsamsten aber ein altind. stamm, der zugleich die bei uns noch erkennbare urbedeutung zeigt, ǵah zappeln, ǵaňghâ das bein vom knöchel bis zum knie Fick vergl. wb. d. indog. spr. (1874) 3, 99, jenes genauer 'mit den flügeln oder beinen schlagen, zappeln', dazu ǵaňghâla schnellfüszig, als subst. antilope u. ä., ǵaňghâ-kara, läufer, eigentlich mit den beinen arbeitend Böhtl.-Roth 3, 9, vgl. 73; das subst. auch im zend, zañga m. 'der obere fusz' (wol vielmehr bein), nizañga 'der untere fusz', s. Justi 120b. 172a. vergl. auch Diefenb. goth. wb. 2, 373.

Demnach war schon im altindischen Stamm mit `ǵaňghâ` bzw. `ǵaňghâla` die baumelnde Bewegung der Beine beim Gehen gemeint, die durchaus auch mit dem Flügelschlagen der Vögel und dem Gang der Antilope benutzt wurde.

So ist es kein Wunder, dass auch heute noch Gehen sowohl beim Menschen, als auch bei Tieren und auch im übertragenen Sinn vorkommt:

> [Pferdegang und Gangarten beim Dressurreiten](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pferdegangart#Grundgangarten)
>   Etwas geht verloren. Etwas geht besser.
>   Die Zeit geht vorüber.
>   Der Hund geht neben dem Jäger.

Demgegenüber stammt [laufen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL02194#XGL02194) aus dem nordischen Sprachraum, wird aber genauso wie *gehen* für Menschen, Tiere und im übertragenen Sinn benutzt, wenn auch mit regionalen Unterschieden, wie bereits berichtet, und eher (aber nicht immer) bei rascheren Bewegungsabläufen.

> [Da packte es der Hund, lief in eine Ecke und fraß es auf.](https://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/der_hund_und_der_sperling)
>   Die Zeit läuft uns davon.
>   Die Flasche läuft aus.

Ich verstehe also beide Beispielsätze aus der Frage gut und empfinde sie auch beide als korrekt. Der Unterschied besteht allenfalls darin, dass die Katze die in die Küche *geht* eher gemächlich unterwegs ist, während die Katze die in die Küche *lief*, vermutlich vom Klappern des Fressnapfes gerufen, ganz schnell dorthin verschwand.

Comment: Wenn man schon Etymologien diskutieren will, dann soll man zumindest moderne wissenschaftliche Quellen konsultieren, wie z.B. Pfeifer. „Grimm“ ist überholt.

Comment: @fdb: Bitteschön: **gehen** bei Pfeifer: [*aind. jáṅghā ‘Unterschenkel’, jáṁhaḥ ‘Flügel, Schwinge’, lit. žeñgti ‘schreiten, gehen’*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gehen) und für **laufen** steht dort: [* (h)loufan (8. Jh.), mhd. loufen, asächs. -hlōpan, (...) got. ushlaupan ‘aufspringen’ sind ie. Verwandte nicht mit Sicherheit nachzuweisen;](https://www.dwds.de/wb/laufen). Also nichts anderes als bei den Grimms. Sprachwissenschaftliche Erkenntnisse veralten vielleicht doch nicht ganz so schnell.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer of mischa.mole](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/41827/1487) is absolutely correct. I just want to add a few more facts:

In the north of German sprachraum *»gehen«* is something that only beings with two legs can do. Beings with four or even more legs can *»laufen«, »krabbeln«, »rennen«, »schleichen«* and much more, but with more than two legs you can't *»gehen«*. (But i'm not sure about birds. They have two legs too, but I'm not sure, if it's ok to say »Das Huhn geht in den Stall« in the north of Germany)

This is very different from the south, where I live. Here in Austria (and I guess in most parts of Bavaria too) *»gehen«* is just walking with all existing legs at a normal speed. And *»laufen«* is a synonym for *»rennen«*, i.e running.

In the north *»laufen«* is a synonym for both, *»gehen«* and *»rennen«*, and it is the standard word that you should use for any animal that is moving with it's legs at normal speed.

---

I give you some examples:

1. A one year old toddler learns to walk:

   In the north:

   > Das Baby lernt laufen.

   In the south:

   > Das Baby lernt gehen. Später, wenn es schon gut genug gehen kann, wird es auch versuchen zu laufen.

   In the south the sentence *»Das Baby lernt laufen«* will be understood as *"the baby learns to run"*.

---

2. On a window shopping expedition:

   In the north:

   > Erika läuft die Straße entlang und bleibt bei jedem Schaufenster stehen.

   In the south:

   > Erika geht die Straße entlang und bleibt bei jedem Schaufenster stehen.

   *»Die Straße entlang laufen«* means *running along the street* in the south. So, the northern sentence will be understood in the south as: *"Erika is sprinting from window to window".*

---

3. A tarantula is slowly crawling across a rock.

   The standard verb for this kind of movement is *»krabbeln«*, but *»gehen/laufen«* is also possible.

   In the north:

   > Die Vogelspinne läuft über den Felsen.

   If you use *»gehen«* in the north, the first association of your listeners maybe is a comic spider, that walks while balancing upright on its two hind legs.

   In the south:

   > Die Vogelspinne geht über den Felsen.

   If you use *»laufen«* in the south, people will understand, that the spider is running.

Comment: I was totally the same opinion, but according to the Duden, gehen implies the use of "Füße", while a cat only has "Pfoten"... https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gehen#Bedeutung1

Comment: @RoyPJ: This is wrong. If you walk on your hands, then this is *gehen* too: »gehen im Handstand«. And Duden doesn't say any word about walking animals.

Comment: That's my point, it does not include animals in the article of *gehen*, but in the article of *laufen* there are animals included. In addition, I would never say *gehen im Handstand*, but *laufen*.

Comment: I would also like to cite the *Spiegel*: "Was im Unterschied zu uns Menschen kein Tier kann, das ist erstens: essen - und zweitens: gehen." http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-vom-fliegen-fahren-gehen-und-laufen-a-471550.html

Comment: Me, having grown up in the South but now predominantly living in the North (of Germany): 1) We would say *Das Baby lernt laufen* anyway. For me *Das Baby lernt gehen* sounds definitely odd; first, in dialect it would be "S Bebi lernt ganga", which is just a non-existing expression, as *ganga* (gehen) is used almost only in the sense of French *partir* (weggehen). 2) As the human brain seeks patterns and sense whereever it can, facing an expression such as "Das Baby lernt gehen", one would perhaps come up with the (still odd) interpretation "Das Baby lernt (die Sportart) Gehen".

Comment: [Continuation from above] 3) Nobody in the South (as far as I have witnessed) would use the word *gehen* for moving activities of insects, arachneae and other such creatures. *Die Spinne geht über den Felsen* evokes a picture of, as in one answer above, a spider equipped with an umbrella or so elegantling walking along a boulevard or so. For me the ordinary (unmarked) verb to use is *krabbeln* or, rarely, *laufen*.

Comment: PS Should have been *arachnida* or simply *arthropods* for all of them. Shame on me.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  I just realize that we see something similar in English.  "The spider ran over the rocks" would be a bit strange and sounds like the spider is wearing tennis shoes.