# What is the difference between renne and laufe?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I understand that both of them mean "run" or "to run".

However, I see laufe, laufen, lauft, etc. used much more often than renne and its other conjugations.

- Is there a time and place to use one over the other?
- Is one more preferred than the other?

Comment: This question has already been answered [over here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44377/rennen-laufen-gehen-wandern-spazieren) :) Therefore, this question is what we call a duplicate of that other one, and it will probably be closed.

Comment: Ja, das beantwortet meine Frage.  Vielen dank!